# Error while calling api using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I am Calling an API with with following with Node.js code but the code is always throwing an error.

Basically I am creating a bot with Microsoft Bot Framework and throwing an image to the API and evalutaing the response

```
    var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var http = require("http");
var request= require("request");
var rest = require('rest');
var server = restify.createServer();

server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () { });
// Create the chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: 'APP_ID',
    appPassword: 'APP_PASS'
});


// Listen for messages from users 
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

server.get('/', restify.plugins.serveStatic({
 directory: __dirname,
 default: '/index.html'
}));


var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session, results) {
  var attachment = session.message.attachments[0];
  request({url: attachment.contentUrl, encoding: null}, function (error, response, body) {
    // Take the image and post to the custom vision service
    rest.post('URL_OF_API' , {
      multipart: true,
      headers: {
        'Prediction-Key': 'KEY',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      data: {
        'filename': rest.data('TEST.png', 'image/png', body)
      }
    }).on('complete', function(data) {
      let men = 0.0; //not-men
      let women = 0.0; //not-women
      let topHit = { Probability: 0.0, Tag: '' }; 

      for (var i = 0; i < data.Predictions.length; i++) {
        if (data.Predictions[i].Tag === 'Men')
          men = data.Predictions[i].Probability;
        else if (data.Predictions[i].Tag === 'Women')
          women = data.Predictions[i].Probability;
        else {
          if (data.Predictions[i].Probability > topHit.Probability)
            topHit = data.Predictions[i];
        }
      }
      let gender = 'No idea';
      if (men > women)
        gender = 'Men';
      if (women > men)
        gender = 'Women';
    var opt='The Pic sent appears to be a'+gender+'or'+gender+'s cloth';
      session.endDialog(opt);
    }).on('error', function(err, response) {
      session.send('Error calling custom vision endpoint');
    }).on('fail', function(data, response) {
      session.send('Failure calling custom vision endpoint');
    });
  });
});
```

I am getting this error

```
'filename': rest.data('TEST.png', 'image/png', body)
                         ^

TypeError: rest.data is not a function
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\Tushar\botforarticle\app.js:39:26)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Tushar\botforarticle\node_modules\request\request.js:188:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tushar\botforarticle\node_modules\request\request.js:1171:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tushar\botforarticle\node_modules\request\request.js:1091:12)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because, well, `rest.data` is indeed not a function.

See the docs:

- https://github.com/cujojs/rest

It's not very clear what are you trying to do here, why are you doing it that way and what have you tried to fix the issue. With more context it would be easier to give you a more specific answer but without enough information all I can tell you is to read the documentation of the module that you're using or to use some other module that may better suit your needs, like request, restler, unirest, superagent or some other HTTP/REST client available in Node.